# How to use pointer from COM object on C#?

Tags: c#, .net

All.

I'm trying to use my old dll file on .net project.
So I converted this unmanaged COM object to managed one by using [tlbimp.exe] util from Windows SDK.

However, one method returns a Object as a return value, but whenever I try to use it, 
my program generates an error.

The weird thing is below:

```
//Object[] item = s.GetObjects(); //this generates an type error
Object item = s.GetObjects(); //this works okay
System.WriteLine(items); //prints System.Object[] rather than System.Object.
```

It seems like it returns a pointer which contains an object array. Isn't it ?
Please anyone tell me how to handle this, and is there any documentation for this issue ?

Comment: Consider adding corresponding line form IDL for `GetObjects` call. It is not possible to reason what should happen by looking at just C# code.

Comment: Thanks:D please see comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this ?

```
Object[] item = s.GetObjects() as Object[];
```

Comment: Never use the *as* in a case like this. Just cast so you get a Good Exception instead of a crappy NRE or an undiagnosed mistake.

Comment: Oh, it works, but now it says "System.__ComObject," and it only has a 1 element.

Comment: It says "COM components that enter the CLR and do not support IProvideClassInfo or that do not have any interop assembly registered will be wrapped in the __ComObject type." I need more investigations.